# Codeigniter active record where() with serialize data and regex

Tags: regex, codeigniter, activerecord, serialization

i want to fetch all the records against a specific user_id, in my table user data is in serialize form in a column (user_data).

```
a:9:{s:9:"auth_type";s:4:"user";s:7:"user_id";s:2:"40";s:9:"user_type";s:1:"2";s:5:"fname";s:9:"Saif Alvi";s:5:"sname";s:0:"";s:8:"nickname";s:8:"saifalvi";s:6:"gender";s:0:"";s:13:"user_type_str";s:8:"employer";s:7:"lang_id";s:1:"1";}
```

to fetch all records against user_id i am using below query

```
$result = $this->DB->select("COUNT(*) AS sessionCount")->from(SESSIONS_TABLE)->where('user_data', REGEXP.'s:7:"user_id";s:"^[0-9]+":'.'"$user_id"')->get()->result_array();
```

where i am wrong or any other solution to use codigniter active record where() with serialize data and regex

Comment: What errors do you have?

Comment: no error...don't get required data